# How to get list of .so that python script use?

Tags: python, cuda, libraries, tensorflow, strace

For example I run `python3 my_script.py`, `my_script.py` uses `tensorflow` package inside, that use cuda libs, how can I get list of `.so` libs that are loaded at script execution?

**UPDATE:**

```
strace -e trace=open python3 my_script.py
```

don't print .so files, also how to suppress output of script itself, i.e. get only output of `strace`?

Comment: Check out this: [How do I monitor opened files of a process in realtime?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58887/117037)

Comment: @wjandrea Updated question.